# How to proxy API REST calls : (FE hosted on Netlify)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post, netlify

When I am going to post a call it is working fine locally and I am able to make the access with netlify but once I am hosting the front end app from Netlify the the POST Proxy is getting set to the netlify URL

The hosted URL : https://deploy-preview-14--hungry-lovelace-df4f46.netlify.app/login

One we click on Sign Up and click on Signup then I see the POST method is going to
https://abc/register

where I need it to go to https://xyztrial.com/register

In local I made it work by adding Proxy: 'xyztrial.com.com' in the Package.json

But once I host it I am not able to post the call, what should I do ?

Screenshot for the same has been added as well as the above URL it can be done online.

Because of which I am getting 404 error Page not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You use the NODE_ENV env variable to switch the base URL from dev to prod, and you use that in your api calls:

```
const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "localhost:5000" : "https://nameofyourapp.herokuapp.com" 

const endpoint = "/api/v1/get-posts"

fetch(baseURL + endpoint)
... 
...
```

This way you won't need proxying in package.json during dev and it will automatically switch in production to your backend URL.

2. Use Netlify Proxies:

> Proxy to another service
> Similar to how you can rewrite paths like /* to /index.html, you can also set up rules to let parts of your site proxy to external services. Let’s say you need to communicate from a single-page app with an API on https://api.example.com that doesn’t support CORS requests. The following rule will let you use /api/ from your JavaScript client:
>
> /api/*  https://api.example.com/:splat  200
>
> Now all requests to /api/... will be proxied through to
> https://api.example.com straight from our CDN servers without an
> additional connection from the browser. If the API supports standard
> HTTP caching mechanisms like ETags or Last-Modified headers, the
> responses will even get cached by our CDN nodes.

https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service

Just remember to enable CORS and place your netlify origin as allowed on your heroku server.

Comment: Hi @Cesare Polonara , I was able to get it with the fist implementation but I stated to get the Cors Error What shall I do ?
 Updated URL : https://625eb54d5feb5600083e8b5d--hungry-lovelace-df4f46.netlify.app/login

Comment: You need to enable cors with cors middleware: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html assuming you are using an express server.

Comment: THanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple and straight forward:-

You need to add file with name "_redirects" in your root directory of your frontend(generally root directory for react is public)

You need to have 2 line of code in that directory:-

1. If your url for making api calls to backend is something like :- `/api/user/signin`
   and suppose your backend is deployed at `https://backend-url.com`, then the first line in your _redirects file will be:-

   /api/*  https://backend-url.com/api/:splat  200
2. In your netlify deployed application, if tou will refresh any route, the "404 page not-found" error will occur. Supposing that index.html is the root file of your frontend, add this line in _redirects:-

   /* /index.html 200